# Unknown Options when Using aws s3 mv

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am getting the error message

> "Unknown options: s3://mybucket/"

when using the following set of commands to mv files to S3. The output that I am getting from `echo $b` is exactly what I am expecting so I know I am targeting the correct file.  The error occurs on the line`aws s3 mv ...`

```
tag=$( tail -n 2 /var/log/cloud-init-output.log )
if [[ ${tag} == *"Processed"* ]]; then
    b=${tag##*"from"}
    b=${b%%.*}  # retain the part before the colon
    aws s3 mv myfolder/ s3://mybucket/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "$b.txt"
fi
```

After messing around with it for a long time, I believe the `$b` variable in the mv command is the issue because it will work if I substitute the output of `echo $b`for `$b` in `$b.txt`.  However, I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Here is the output when I run `aws --version`:

```
aws-cli/1.14.8 Python/2.7.14 Linux/4.14.47-64.38.amzn2.x86_64 botocore/1.8.12
```

which is the latest version and I have already tried running (I have python3 installed):

```
pip3 install --upgrade awscli
```

I know wildcards are weird with the aws-cli but I don't see why I would get an error using a variable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting an `echo` in front of `aws s3 mv` to see what command it is attempting to execute.

Comment: `echo sudo aws s3 mv myfolder/ s3://mybucket/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "$b.txt"` outputs `sudo aws s3 mv myfolder/ s3://mybucket/ --recursive --exclude * --include  account_dim.txt` which is the proper name of the file.  Then when I copy and paste the echo and put the quotations back in around `"*"` and `"account_dim.txt"`, it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `--exclude "*" --include "$b.txt"`, I just used `aws s3 mv myfolder/"$b.txt" s3://mybucket/`. I'm pretty sure I tried that same thing earlier without the "" around $b.txt and it didn't work because there was a whitespace in front of the variable.